# How to determine throughput/bandwidth from a file captured

Tags: python, pcap, tshark, throughput, pchar

I need to determine the throughput available between TCP client/server based on a packet capture.

I would be very grateful if someone would indicate a script or tool that allows me to extract the throughput or network bandwidth from a pcap file and save it in a csv, txt, etc.

Any help will be really appreciated
Laura

Comment: Take a look at this: https://www.wireshark.org/docs/man-pages/capinfos.html and this: https://serverfault.com/questions/521043/tcpdump-how-to-check-rate-of-packets

Comment: Thanks @Mondo-Cane, but capinfo gives me the information of the whole pcap and I want the Throughput for each packet (e.g TCP packets)

Comment: If this a question from a class, they probably want you to look at the fields in the TCP packets to determine what the highest possible throughput could be (as they are related).